# WF - Creating a selective list

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a stupid question. I have created a workflow Designer host where I publish my own activities. I also have a property grid which only displays the properties decorated with a special attribute. This designer is going to be used by none IT staff.

What I want is that on an activity the user can select a property value from a list. I know I just could create an Enum but I would like it to be dynamic. I.e. all events on a specific interface (extracted using reflection).

Is this at all possible or am I stuck with enums?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, once again I manage to ask a question and then find the answer my self.

The answer is TypeConverter.